# RMYSQL- Insert Ignore, Replace -R

Tags: r, rmysql

I am exporting data to a MySQL database from R using the `RMySQL` package. A big problem I am facing is duplicates: I have too many entries with same values. The system automatically produces the results and inserts the dataframe into the database.

Current Table in DB:

```
Name   Balance  
Bob      100
Ted      150
Carl     130
```

I also have a data frame (`df`) in R reflecting changed balances:

```r
> df
    Name   Balance
[1] Bob      100
[2] Ted      150
[3] Bill     50
```

Data to be inserted in DB:

```r
Name   Balance
Bill     50
```

Now after insertion, Table should look like this:

```
Name   Balance
 Bob      100
 Ted      100
 Carl     130
 Bill     50
```

But my dbwrite produces this:

```
Name   Balance
 Bob      100
 Ted      100
 Carl     130
 Bob      100
 Ted      150
 Bill     50
```

I am using this code:

```r
dbWriteTable(con, "DB Table name", rbind(Dataframe), row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

Is there any way to check for existing ones and update the table with only new ones using RMYSQL in R.

Comment: does your mysql table have indexes? specifically, is there a unique index that may allow you to perform an `insert ... on duplicate key ...`

Comment: How about reading in existing rows from DB to dataframe, compare with new data, and only dbWriteTable the difference?

Comment: @zx8754 Yes I thought of it as well, But the table gets bigger and bigger every day. Reading it into R will take more time.

Comment: @Barranka Yes Its has unique index.. but I dont think insert ON DUPLICATE key option is available in RMySQL package.

Comment: If there's a UNIQUE index, then why is the data inserted to the table? It should return an error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `dbWriteTable()` use `dbSendQuery()`. You can build an SQL query to insert each row of the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('Bob','Ted','Bill'), balance=c(100,150,50))
strSQL <- paste(
  'insert into your_table (name, balance) values',
  paste(sprintf("('%s', %f)", df$name, df$balance), collapse=', '),
  'on duplicate key update balance = values(balance)',
  sep = ' '
)
# The query will be something like this:
#           insert into your_table (name, balance)
#           values ('Bob', 100.000000), ('Ted', 150.000000), ('Bill', 50.000000) 
#           on duplicate key update balance = values(balance);
# Important: If you want this to work, you must ensure that there's a unique
# index on column 'name' in your_table
dbSendQuery(con, strSQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your query and got an error.                    Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1)

Comment: @AishwaryaaViswanathan Sorry! Missed the last part of the SQL sentence: `on duplicate key update balance = values(balance)`. I've just edited the answer with the correction. Should work now

Comment: It's better to use dbGetQuery because that automatically closes the result set. You should also either quote values or use a parameterised query in order to protect against SQL injection attacks

Comment: @hadley could you please post a link or reference on how to use prepared statements with `RMySQL`? I haven't found anything about it (and I've searched)

Comment: It's mostly in the dev version - https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL. Will work on an overview doc soon